# Size of canvas in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

In my app I need to know how big the canvas is *in pixels*.

Instead calling `canvas.size` returns `[100,100]` no matter how many pixels the canvas is wide.

Can you please tell me a way to get how many pixels the canvas is wide and high?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no position nor size in a Canvas. Canvas act just as a container for graphics instructions, like Fbo that draw within a Texture, so it have a size.

In Kivy, Canvas.size doesn't exists, but i guess you called your widget a canvas. By default, a Widget size is 100, 100. If you put it into a layout, the size will be changed, when the layout will known its own size. Mean, you need to listen to the changes of the Widget.size, or use a size you known, like Window.size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996162/setting-kivy-window-size-not-working

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna guess that you actually need the window size in order to know what your image boundaries are. In this case, you can use:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
size = Window.size
```

And you can of course use the source image of your canvas with PIL or scipy etc. to get its resolution (which the canvas will match).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the canvas has a "size" of (100,100) whatever you do. The size you are looking for must be the widget size e.g.
If you have a FloatLayout and want to draw on it a rect that fills it
try:

```
f = FloatLayout
Rectangle(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0}, size=f.size)
```

and not

```
Rectangle(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0}, size=f.canvas.size)
```