# Kivy: Spinner import changes application size

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

i have a really strange problem. Since half a year i'm writing an application using kivy. The application will run on a Raspberry Pi with a touch screen. So for developing and checking if the layout looks fine i'm setting the application size to the touchscreen resolution at the very beginning of my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')
```

Until now i just used the pure spinner class, without any problems. But now i need to create a custom spinner but i can't get it to work, even with the most basic code:

my_spinner.py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

Builder.load_file('my_spinner.kv')


class MySpinner(Spinner):

    pass
```

my_spinner.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<MySpinner>:
```

As soon as i just add

```
#:import MySpinner my_spinner.MySpinner
```

to any other kv-file the application size changes. Respectively, the Config.set() seems to be ignored.
Does anyone have a clue what's going on here? To me this makes absolutely no sense.
(I hope these snippets are enough. The project is quiet huge and complex.)

Thanks in advance

Edit: This happens just with the spinner class. If 'MySpinner' inherits the button class, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years passed by and I'm still working on the same application.
Today I had the same problem, as soon as I added

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
```

to my code the `Config.set()` got ignored. I could fix this by replaying the `Config.set()` by `Window.size` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37035190).